# alert in foreach with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, alert

When I update many items it return many alerts.
I have this code

```
inputs.forEach(input => {
    $.post("/update.php",
      {price: input.id},
                
      function(result) {
        alert("cargo updated successfully")
     });

})
```

how can I get alert only one time in this case?

Comment: FYI, alerts are terrible UX. They require action from your users, which isn't convenient, and they aren't stylable. Consider in-page messaging, self-dismissing toast notifications, or a custom modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

`$.post` returns a [thenable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#thenables)

Given an array of thenables, [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will return a promise that resolves when *all* the thenables are resolved.

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will return an array of results for a function (unlike `forEach` which returns nothing).

Put them together:

```js
Promise.all(
    inputs.map(
        input => $.post("/update.php", {price: input.id})
    )
).then(() => alert("cargo updated successfully"));
```

(This assumes that `inputs` is an array. It's quite likely it is a NodeList, in which case you will need to convert it to an array first: `[...inputs].map(etc)`)